# Showing part of UserControl like CroppedBitmap

Tags: wpf, user-controls, crop

I can't English very well yet. please understand even if you can't understand me clearly.

I have huge data table in UserControl.xaml, but downscale this UserControl object showing whole in MainWindow.

I want same size datatable showing of partially UserControl in MainWindow.

Like this image display way:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="<path to source image>" SourceRect="20,20,50,50"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Showing `UserControl` in MainWindow like a SourceRect.

Comment: you should try some WPF tutorials to learn about WPF

Comment: could you please add some image link here in comment so that it will be easy to understand that what you are getting on your screen and what are you expecting now..add image of your output and required output.

Comment: You might want to use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I using ScrollViewer, get it alike effect. but I'm studying to Answer way. Thank you All. happy new year :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have several options. The first way, and I think the easiest is to use `ViewBox` control.

**`1. ViewBox`**

The [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control inherited from `Decorator` is used to stretch or scale a child element, but it is scaled proportionally, ie you can not set the him size such 300x100.

`Example`

```
<Viewbox Width="300"
         Height="300">

    <DataGrid>
    ...
    </DataGrid>
</ViewBox>
```

The second way is to use a screen capture of your control, that you would like to show, and then if you want to use `CroppedBitmap`.

**`2. Capturing screen`**

I found a great article by `Pete Brown` on this subject here:

[`Capturing Screen Images in WPF using GDI, Win32 and a little WPF Interop Help`](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/02/08/capturing-screen-images-in-wpf-using-gdi-win32-and-a-little-wpf-interop-help)

In this article is an example, and it looks like this:

`ScreenCapture`

```
class ScreenCapture
{
    public static BitmapSource CaptureFullScreen(bool addToClipboard)
    {
        return CaptureRegion(
            User32.GetDesktopWindow(),
            (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft,
            (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop,
            (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth,
            (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight,
            addToClipboard);
    }

    // capture a window. This doesn't do the alt-prtscrn version that loses the window shadow.
    // this version captures the shadow and optionally inserts a blank (usually white) area behind
    // it to keep the screen shot clean
    public static BitmapSource CaptureWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool recolorBackground, Color substituteBackgroundColor, bool addToClipboard)
    {
        Int32Rect rect = GetWindowActualRect(hWnd);

        Window blankingWindow = null;

        if (recolorBackground)
        {
            blankingWindow = new Window();

            blankingWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            blankingWindow.Title = string.Empty;
            blankingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            blankingWindow.AllowsTransparency = true;
            blankingWindow.Background = new SolidColorBrush(substituteBackgroundColor);
            blankingWindow.Show();

            int fudge = 20;

            blankingWindow.Left = rect.X - fudge / 2;
            blankingWindow.Top = rect.Y - fudge / 2;
            blankingWindow.Width = rect.Width + fudge;
            blankingWindow.Height = rect.Height + fudge;

        }

        // bring the to-be-captured window to capture to the foreground
        // there's a race condition here where the blanking window
        // sometimes comes to the top. Hate those. There is surely
        // a non-WPF native solution to the blanking window which likely
        // involves drawing directly on the desktop or the target window

        User32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

        BitmapSource captured = CaptureRegion(
            hWnd,
            rect.X,
            rect.Y,
            rect.Width,
            rect.Height, 
            true);

        if (blankingWindow != null)
            blankingWindow.Close();

        return captured;
    }

    // capture a region of the full screen
    public static BitmapSource CaptureRegion(int x, int y, int width, int height, bool addToClipboard)
    {
        return CaptureRegion(User32.GetDesktopWindow(), x, y, width, height, addToClipboard);
    }

    // capture a region of a the screen, defined by the hWnd
    public static BitmapSource CaptureRegion(
        IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool addToClipboard)
    {
        IntPtr sourceDC = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr targetDC = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr compatibleBitmapHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        BitmapSource bitmap = null;

        try
        {
            // gets the main desktop and all open windows
            sourceDC = User32.GetDC(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
            //sourceDC = User32.GetDC(hWnd);
            targetDC = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(sourceDC);

            // create a bitmap compatible with our target DC
            compatibleBitmapHandle = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(sourceDC, width, height);

            // gets the bitmap into the target device context
            Gdi32.SelectObject(targetDC, compatibleBitmapHandle);

            // copy from source to destination
            Gdi32.BitBlt(targetDC, 0, 0, width, height, sourceDC, x, y, Gdi32.SRCCOPY);

            // Here's the WPF glue to make it all work. It converts from an 
            // hBitmap to a BitmapSource. Love the WPF interop functions
            bitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                compatibleBitmapHandle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            if (addToClipboard)
            {
                //Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap); // high memory usage for large images
                IDataObject data = new DataObject();
                data.SetData(DataFormats.Dib, bitmap, false);
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, false);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ScreenCaptureException(string.Format("Error capturing region {0},{1},{2},{3}", x, y, width, height), ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Gdi32.DeleteObject(compatibleBitmapHandle);

            User32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, sourceDC);
            User32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, targetDC);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    // this accounts for the border and shadow. Serious fudgery here.
    private static Int32Rect GetWindowActualRect(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        Win32Rect windowRect = new Win32Rect();
        Win32Rect clientRect = new Win32Rect();

        User32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, out windowRect);
        User32.GetClientRect(hWnd, out clientRect);

        int sideBorder = (windowRect.Width - clientRect.Width)/2 + 1;   

        // sooo, yeah.
        const int hackToAccountForShadow = 4;

        Win32Point topLeftPoint = new Win32Point(windowRect.Left - sideBorder, windowRect.Top - sideBorder);

        //User32.ClientToScreen(hWnd, ref topLeftPoint);

        Int32Rect actualRect = new Int32Rect(
            topLeftPoint.X, 
            topLeftPoint.Y,
            windowRect.Width + sideBorder * 2 + hackToAccountForShadow,
            windowRect.Height + sideBorder * 2 + hackToAccountForShadow);

        return actualRect;
    }
}
```

Example of using:

```
private void CaptureRegionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CapturedImage.Source = ScreenCapture.CaptureRegion(100, 100, 500, 500, true);
}

private void CaptureScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CapturedImage.Source = ScreenCapture.CaptureFullScreen(true);
}
```